# FireGestures script to call extension function

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, xul

How does one invoke a function provided by a Firefox extension, inside FireGestures User Script? For example, I frequently use  [deskCut](http://deskcut.mozdev.org/installation.html)'s context menu command to make desktop url shortcut files. I've downloaded the latest [xpi](https://legacycollector.org/firefox-addons/66/index.html) file. Therein, in the file "deskcutOverlay.xul", section on "contentAreaContextMenu",  I saw the main function referred to as

```
net.evelands.deskcut.create()
```

But simply calling it like that in the body of the User Script does nothing.

Answer (score 0):

OK, now it works exactly like that. I had to change something inside deskcut code, relax the assumption that it's always called from the context menu. Now I can also call it with a mouse gesture or even via a keyboard shortcut!